# Correct modification of ES6 Map through setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using a ES6 Map in my react component state and I was wondering what is the correct way to update it through setState.

I was thinking of something like this

```
let clonedMap = new Map(myMap)      // make a shallow copy of the Map

clonedMap.set('key', 'value')       // modify the copy
clonedMap.delete('foo')             

this.setState({ myMap: clonedMap }) // set the copy as new state
```

Is this the right way to do it ? Shouldn't the copy be a deep copy instead ?

Comment: You should make use of deep copy only if you make deep comparisons somewhere in your lifecycle functions

Comment: Deep copying a `Map` is inefficient. If you want to do that, you should consider using immutable.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes a shallow copy, modifying `myMap` by new reference `clonedMap`, and you want to gave that new reference to the `state`.

If the real purpose is that you want a new `Map` has properties just like you defined in an old `Map` , I suggest using `Object` instead. It's easier to deep clone "those" properties when you use `Object`. Or just define those properties in a new `Map` again.

Here is a [thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160411/deep-clone-objects) discussing data structure deep clone in JavaScript.

If you just want to update the `Map` in the state, code below just goes fine:

```
this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
    prevState.myMap.set('key', 'value');
    prevState.myMap.delete('foo');
    return {
        myMap: prevState.myMap
    }
});
```

[Live Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x2m9l8l6k)

from [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> ... prevState is a reference to the previous state ...

just several lines later

> ... The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState ...

the updater in sentence is `setState()`.